# Creating HTML Email Templates in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've been asked to create a HTML email template in ExactTarget, and after having read the documentation I have a few questions. Thanks in advance for your help.

Is this the only tag available to mark a user editable area?

```
 <custom type="content" name="Content Area 1">
```

Are there any other options available, eg. repeating elements a la Campaign Monitor templates?

Can I, for example, specify that the content should be an image, and that the image should have a fixed width?

Can I set default content for these areas?

The template requires a tracking pixel. Is there a tag in the HTML that will do this without having to manually insert it via a menu?

Does ExactTarget automatically inline styles I've added to a style block on send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - this is how ExactTarget creates content areas and the areas are not restrictive.

In order to track emails, simply insert `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking">` into the bottom of your code, before the `</body>`.

ExactTarget does not automatically inline style - this would be something you would have to do prior to saving.

Comment: I was wondering why the custom "opencounter" tag at the end of ExactTarget email doesn't include a closing tag? shouldn't it be: `<custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"></ custom> </body> </html>` My code editor always flags that unclosed tag.

Comment: i AM guessing here, but since the this is part of the templating language, we should be save to assume that this snippet will be replaced by the system before sending out the email